# Block capacity - Hyperledger Besu

Tags: private-blockchain, nodejs, gas-limit, blocks, besu

Good afternoon,

I am trying to perform a transaction capacity test on my network with Hyperledger Besu with 4 validator nodes and a time per block of 4seconds.

I have created a script with NodeJS that basically creates transactions and launches them against the endpoint of one of my nodes.

The problem is that my network only processes a maximum of 4 to 7 tx per block, even though the gas limit is about 40M and these transactions spend about 2.5M only.

Should I configure something else to make the blocks accept more tx in each block?

I suspect that since all transactions are launched from the same address, you may have to wait for the nonce?

[image: Script]

[image: Ethstats]

Comment: Did you ever find out more about this? I'm curious as well.

Comment: Nop, still wondering why

Comment: My guess is that you indeed have to wait for the nonce or increment nonce on your side. But if you send all tx using the current nonce +1 only the first one will pass.